# How to handle an api with severe technical debt?

Tags: api, ios, json, technical-debt

Our company uses another companys api. This api is written using IBM domino. This api is horrifically inconsistent and outdated. E.g. sometimes returning JSON, sometimes html. Inconsistent naming and types.
What would be the best course of action? I don't think we can force them to update their api. Would it be best to implement a "sanity layer" in our client to manipulate the json response to be consistent? Or just deal with complexity directly when serializing the json?

Comment: Look into the [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) design pattern.